# sudo bash can't execute script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I try to run a shell script file but failed so far on Ubuntu.

In my terminal:

```
~/Desktop/FTL/data$ ls
amd64  exe_icon.bmp  FTL  licenses  resources  x86
~/Desktop/FTL/data$ sudo bash ./FTL.sh
[sudo] password for anon: 
bash: ./FTL.sh: No such file or directory
~/Desktop/FTL/data$ sh FTL.sh
sh: 0: Can't open FTL.sh
~/Desktop/FTL/data$
```

Comment: You can use `file FTL` and the system will do its best to work out what it is and tell you.

Answer (score 11):

Well, as can be deduced from the output of `ls` command, the name of the file is `FTL`, not `FTL.sh`. So you should use:

```
sudo bash ./FTL
```

or

```
 sh ./FTL
```

or maybe only:

```
./FTL
```

Also be sure that the file is executable, by running:

```
chmod +x FTL
```

Answer (score 1):

First thought is change the extension to `.sh`. Should be able to run as `./FTL.sh`.
Second, if it's missing the `#!/bin/sh` at the top of the file, it won't work then either.

Third, if you wind up having `sudo` commands intermixed with commands that don't require `sudo`, you can `echo <sudo_password> | command`.

In this case, best practice (from an automation/QA perspective) is to run your command as `./FTL.sh <sudo_password>` and capture the password to use later in the script for each command that will prompt for sudo password.

ex:

```
#!/bin/sh
PW=$1 #sets first parameter
...
# non-sudo commands
...
echo $PW | command`
```

It's also not a bad idea to throw in a `yes |` when your command asks if you want to continue for any reason. Then you can modify the above to `echo $PW | yes | command`

I also typically capture all output during testing, which can be accomplished by appending `|& tee path/to/logfile.log` to the end of any command, if you want to watch it progress in the console, or switch the `|& tee` to `&>` if it has a long run time or otherwise don't want to monitor progress.

ex:

```
if echo $PW | yes | command |& tee path/to/logfile.log; then 
  if sed -Fq "Validation Passed" path/to/logfile.log; then
    echo "PASS: returned 'Validation Pass'"
    else echo "FAIL: test did not return 'Validation Pass'"
  fi
  else echo "Test Failed"
fi
```

Just a quickie on the sed command, `-F` allows you to specify the file name (instead of searching a process output) and `-q` runs sed quietly and exits after it finishes searching the file/process. See [sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Always use this command for every script to be executed by server.

```
chmod +x filename.ext
```